# Call random audio file on image roll-over

Tags: javascript, html, audio, rollover

I have a HTML page with an image in it.
When I roll-over the image with my mouse it plays an audio file.

I have 4 different audio files, and each time I roll-over the image I need it to play the next audio-file in the sequence.

I've got it playing one audio-file back ok, but how do I get it calling the next audio-file in the queue?

Comment: Please show us some code - what did you do so far?

Comment: `array = ["audio_file_name1", "audio_file_name1" , ...]` , each time you call roll-over. Change the elements file name to `array[i + 1]`, go from `0 to n-1`, and have it loop back to `i = 0` when `i > n - 1`. Basically we just loop through and array by step each function call.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. @Charles - that works a treat. Check out what we did here, it was a bit of fun :) - http://infinite-awesome.com/noentrada/

Answer (score 0):

Its likely you just need to make a javascript function on the webpage to handle this.    Without seeing your codes I can't really give you a good example.  Here is what I would do.  Within a a script tag or head javascript:

```
var current = 0;
var musicList = ["file1.wav", "file2.wav" , ...];

function playSound()
{
    // Code to play audio file
    // you don't need to bother with <audio> elements. 
    // HTML 5 lets you access audio API directly
    // buffers automatically when created
    var snd = new Audio(musicList[current]);
    snd.play();

    // code to increment and current counter (depending on musicList size)
    current++;
    current = current % musicList.length;
}
```

Within your HTML, you can just rely on javascript to do the work by using the onmouseover or onmouseout tag.

```
<img onmouseover="playSound();" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley">
```

Comment: Craig could you please make this as the correct answer?